# Access data inside JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a variable **$output** in PHP with this inside:

```
   {
"results": [
    {
        "address_components": [
            {
                "long_name": "6",
                "short_name": "6",
                "types": [
                    "street_number"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "",
                "short_name": "",
                "types": [
                    "route"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "",
                "short_name": "",
                "types": [
                    "locality",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Barcelona",
                "short_name": "Barcelona",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_2",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Catalunya",
                "short_name": "CT",
                "types": [
                    "administrative_area_level_1",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "Spain",
                "short_name": "ES",
                "types": [
                    "country",
                    "political"
                ]
            },
            {
                "long_name": "0830",
                "short_name": "0830",
                "types": [
                    "postal_code"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "formatted_address": "Barcelona, Spain",

"status": "OK"
}
```

I want to access the data inside **"formatted_address"** and store it's value in a variable in PHP so i can later store it on my database. I have tried so many things, but no success.

this is what i tried:

```
$info= json_decode($output); 
echo $info->results;
echo $info->results[0];
echo $info.results;
echo $info['results']
etc... etc...
```

Could you please tell me how exactly do i access this information in PHP?

Help please!

Comment: What have you tried?  The PHP docs have info on how to parse JSON.

Comment: @Ray post-edited

Comment: $info->results[0]-formatted_address I think. That would just be the first one though as it's an array of objects.

Comment: @blacksmith try using `var_dump` instead of `echo` and post the results. Also check out the link that @marekful mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost!

`$info->results[0]->formatted_address`

Also, try using [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for better output on php objects.

Answer (score 0):

Or as one line:

```
echo json_decode($output)->results[0]->formatted_address;
```